# FTP files opened from Nautilus opens in Firefox instead of default application (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, firefox, ftp, default-programs

I often use Nautilus to connect to my ftp server.  Whenever I open a remote file from nautilus (even when it states that the default program is something like gedit) it still opens that file in firefox. Choosing the "Open with Other Application" option works, but it's annoying having to do that every time.  I remember reading that this is a known bug and it has to do with some other application/library and not with Nautilus, but I can't find url to that bug anymore.

Again, This is only an issue when opening remote/ftp files and is not an issue with local files.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1742482

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mainly want to edit files with gedit, you can add the following line to *~/.config/mimeapps.list*

```
x-scheme-handler/ftp=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
```

Put it under the block "Default Applications". It works for me, but it sets the default program for ALL ftp-files to gedit.

Comment: Tested and confirmed that this works.  Thank you so much!

Comment: IMHO this is a bad workaround, because now also JPG open in Gedit. Right click, open with other program and then selecting the program DOES work. But it's a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

list ftp handlers

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/ftp
```

set gedit as default ftp handler

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/ftp gedit.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you using FTP protocol. I don't know is it the normal behaviour of Nautilius but if you mount an FTP drive with it will download files from it and not open them. To **open files** directly like on a local machine use SMB (Samba) protocol instead FTP in Nautilius.

Example:

FTP protocol

```
ftp://192.168.1.1/yoursharedfolder
```

SMB protocol

```
smb://192.168.1.1/yoursharedfolder
```